# realpath($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]) not working on Windows

Tags: php

I get this error:
Warning: require_once(C:\xampp\htdocs/models/config.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\venture\html\admin\index.php on line 3

Here is the code where the error appears:

```
$root = realpath($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]);
require_once($root . "/models/config.php");
```

Comment: Double check your paths. "DOCUMENT_ROOT" is not the same directory you are in. XAMPP messes with directories.

Answer (score 1):

you need change slash

```
$root = realpath(str_replace('\\', '/', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']) );
require_once($root . "/models/config.php");
```

Comment: will this be working for linux too? also you have one parenthesis extra

Comment: will work for linux to 100% i am using it all the time